# Error 403 when requesting Clash Royale api

Tags: javascript

Where is the problem with my code?
I have requested to use the Clash Royale api using the code below, but I am getting an error.
Is it my country's problem?
Because I am from Iran
If you have a better way to get the clash royale api and put it in the tag, please help me

```js
let token = "<snip>"




function PlayerInfo(){


fetch('https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/tournaments',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        "Authorization": Bearer = token
        }
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(date => {
    document.querySelector("#p").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(date)
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    

<button onclick="PlayerInfo()">PlayerInfo</button>
<br>
<hr>
<div id="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus sapiente illum cumque illo eius voluptatum? Voluptas accusantium in dicta laudantium itaque! Numquam, dolorum aut. Temporibus autem blanditiis architecto doloremque beatae.</div>



</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZpg0.jpg)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```{  ...  "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` }``` ? Because `Bearer = token` resolves to `token`.

Comment: I did this
But I ran into the first problem again

Comment: could you post an image of the request response?. I mean in the response tab not in headers.

Comment: I just uploaded it

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the Authorization header incorrectly, it should be

```
"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token
```

Comment: I did this
But I ran into the first problem again

Comment: You haven't posted the actual error in the question. The error returned by the clash api should contain some information.

Comment: I posted a picture of my error.
If you have a better way to use clash royale api please help me